# Using SwitftUI, how do I vary the font size of a Text?

Tags: ios, swiftui, font-size

I have an array of words. I need to display them on multiple lines, several words per line, each word using a different letter size. The letter size for each word will to be determined programatically. A familiar example would be one of those word frequency displays that shows the most common words in the largest size. Can I make that kind of display with swiftUI?

From the documentation of 'Text' I don't see a way to specify a numerical size, just a style such as .title. I understand that specifying a numerical font size may not be device-independent, but how else can I make the display that I'm looking for? Can I programmatically define a font style with a parameterized size so I can specify it numerically for each separate word? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the size of text like this

```
Text("hello")
    .font(.system(size: 12))
```